# AttributeError: not found module 'time' has no attribute 'clock'

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Mata Kuliah\Semester VI\Bahan Sistem Tersebar\concurrent_futures_pooling.py", line 20, in <module>   
    start_time = time.clock()
AttributeError: module 'time' has no attribute 'clock'
```

Comment: How did you import `time`? `import time` or `from time import time`? you need the first.

Comment: @Guy That doesn't matter since Python 3's `time` module doesn't have `clock`.

Answer (score 3):

The `time` built-in module indeed doesn't have a `clock()` export in Python 3.8.

You'll need to adapt your (apparently Python 2 or 3.x (where x < 8) compatible) code to be compatible with Python 3.8.

`time.clock()` was generally used for high-resolution "stopwatch" timing. The replacement in Python 3.3+ is `time.perf_counter()`.

Comment: Actually it was removed in Python 3.8 (and deprecated since 3.3) https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#api-and-feature-removals. You can also see in `time.pyi` `if sys.version_info < (3, 8): def clock() -> float: ...`

Comment: @Guy Ah, fair enough. I just peeked at my local Python docs (which are probably for 3.10)